# how to delete the record of smart completions in firefox add-on vimperator

Tags: firefox-addon, vimperator

how can I delete one or some link in smart completions of firefox add-on vimperator? i.e. delete the record of smart completions?
Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Is this a question about programming some method of doing this, or are you looking for some way for you, as a user, to make such changes?

Comment: You will probably get better response using the contact info. for vimperator: "Please send comments/bug reports/patches to the mailing list, where a lively community will properly answer most questions. If you don't have a google account, you should also be able to join the mailing list by sending an e-mail to vimperator-labs+subscribe@googlegroups.com. You can also join the #vimperator IRC channel on irc.freenode.net." Or contact information on [vimperator's AMO page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimperator/): email:vimperator@mozdev.org, site:http://www.vimperator.org/